# Preventing 1st Column Blank pages from printing in the middle of the project

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2013

I have an MS-Project that has approximately 300 tasks and is spread over about 6 years.  When I attempt to print on tabloid for all dates and pages, it shows me a nice 5 row, 4 column grid.  When I go into page setup -> View, I have a check in the boxes for print first 3 columns on all pages, and fit timescale to end of page selected.  The print blank pages box is empty.

As a result of the print blank pages being empty, certain pages in my grid are greyed out...but not all the empty pages are.  All the pages in the 1st column get printed even if they are blank.

[image: Example 1 pic]

The second part is trying to print only specific pages.  I select Print Specific pages but it appears to only allow you to select a range.  I would like to print pages 1,6,7,12-14,19,20.  I was hoping there was a way to do this similar to excel, word where you can specify multiple pages with a break in the range.

[image: Example 2 pic]

1)  Is there any way to avoid printing the blank pages in the first column?

2)  How can you print multiple specific pages?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a load of different answers on this so I'll add a couple of tips that helped me.

1. Change the Print to manually define the start and end dates.
   [image: Print Dialog Box]

---

2. Un-tick the Drawings option
   [image: Layout Dialog Box]